# Can't get nmap info from Brainpan2

Tags: virtualization, nmap

I'm trying to setup an environment in VirtualBox for exploiting Brainpan2 (from Vulnhub). I created 2 VMs (Brainpan2 and Kali) but when I try to perform an `nmap -A` scan on the other 3 IP addresses on the network, it returns all of the info on my host machine (Win 7, etc) How do I get info on the Brainpan machine?

Comment: This looks like a VirtualBox networking setup issue.

Comment: you need to explain your VM and networking setup

Comment: Might be a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/1018248/new-vm-does-not-autoconnect-to-the-internet-which-setting-do-i-need-in-vmware-f/1018269#1018269