# New VM Does Not Autoconnect To The Internet, Which Setting Do I Need in VMWare Fusion?

Tags: networking, vmware-fusion

I'm using VMWare Fusion 7.1 on Mac OS X. All the VM's that I've downloaded connect to the internet automatically when I fire them up. I downloaded a new VM from VulnHub, specifically BrainPan2. (Here is the info about it if needed: https://www.vulnhub.com/entry/brainpan_2,56/)

This one does not connect to the internet automatically even though it is supposed to. It is a vulnerable VM setup for security penetration testing. Now, I fire up my Kali VM, do a network scan, and see all my computers. I'll fire up an unrelated virtual machine, run the scan again, and confirm that the new one appears. Now, I fire up BrainPan, run the scan, and nothing. I don't see it on the scan.

I've read multiple guides related to the BrainPan2 VM from the internet, and everyone else seems to be able to plug it in and go. From the BrainPan site:

> It will get an IP address via DHCP,

So, I've set the VM to run on NAT, Bridged and also Host. I cannot detect the VM by any means, it just doesn't auto-connect. And I obviously can't login and hook it up since it's made to hack. Upon my research, I've found another similar question on this site but the gentleman provided no info in his question:
[Can't get nmap info from Brainpan2](https://superuser.com/questions/1014480/cant-get-nmap-info-from-brainpan2)

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Edit: It states in this article: http://blog.techorganic.com/2013/11/19/brainpan-2-hacking-challenge/

> Brainpan 2 has been tested and found to work on the following
>   hypervisors:
>
> VMware Player 6.0.1 ,
>   VMWare Fusion 6.0.2 ,
>   VirtualBox 4.3.2 Import
>
> brainpan2.ova into your preferred hypervisor and configure the network
>   settings to your needs. It will get an IP address via DHCP, but it's
>   recommended you run it within a NAT or visible to the host OS only
>   since it is vulnerable to attacks.

I'm on VMWare Fusion 7.1.x, could that be the issue?

Comment: Can you login to the VM and check to make sure it is getting an IP address?  Just because it says it should automatically get an ip via DHCP, does not mean that whomever developed the VM might have decided to disable the adapter until you go in and enable it for the first time.  Just throwing ideas out there

Comment: Also for situations like yours, unless the Kali Install is also a VM running via virtual box on the same computer as the VM you are having issues with, you will probably want to use bridged mode for your adapter otherwise you will not be able to see the VM from any machine on your network.  NAT mode introduces a whole new subnet for communications between VMs.

Comment: @Richie086 Unfortunately I can only login as a guest user, and it didn't assign anything in that scenario. That is really good to know! Thank you. I'm running Kali as a VM on NAT currently and have been for a while, should I keep it that way?

Comment: Also, both the VM's are on the same computer, my Mac running OS X.

Comment: John do you see the adapter in the problem VM when you run ifconfig?  Does it show eth0 (which is usually your primary Ethernet adapter)?   Both VMs can run in NAT mode as long as you do not need to scan or connect to any resources on either VM outside of virtual box.  If you want to communicate with either VM you should use bridged mode because then you should get an IP address from your routers DHCP server instead of the internal virtual box DHCP server.

Comment: The issue could be the hyper visor now that I am rereading your post.  I thought you were using virtual box for some reason.

Comment: @Richie086 Thank you so much for the explanation! That makes sense. I'm using Kali to pentest the VM, both on the same computer so I will use Bridged Mode on both machines and see if nmap picks it up. Oh I'm actually using the Mac version of VMWare, VMWare Fusion 7.1.x

Comment: Is there any way you could download virtual box and test to see if you get an IP address when you use a hyper visor that the developers say is supported?

Comment: If both VMs are on the same machine, NAT should be ok.  Just keep in mind you won't be able to scan those machines outside of the internally NATed network.

Comment: @Richie086 Oh perfect that makes sense, that sounds like just what I need. I will hook them both up to NAT. I ran `ifconfig` on the VM and it actually gave me an address now, though nmap on the second machine doesn't detect it. I will give it a try on Virtual Box if I can find a free copy

Comment: Lucky for you virtual box is free!  Let me know if that works and if it does I will convert my comment into an answer so if someone else has a similar issue it can be resolved.

Comment: @Richie086 Hooking them both up to NAT as you recommended worked and NMap is picking it up! Thank you so much Richie. Yeah that would be awesome if you could make it an answer so that I can up vote ya!

Comment: Done.  Glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consolidation of the comment stream above.

Jons issue was that he was using the wrong type of network adapter inside of VMware. The VM in question was not receiving an IP address so when he would go to scan it using nmap, he was not seeing the virtual machine.

The solution was to make sure both VM's we're using NAT instead of bridged mode so they could communicate with each other each other.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and knowledge that you have provided Richie!